# Build problem with React viteJS and was amplify

Tags: reactjs, build, aws-amplify, vite

my question is quite simple to explain. I've initialized a React project with ViteJS and then added aws-amplify for the backend. I developed the project and everything works in my local environment running npm run dev. The problem is that I cannot build it.
You can see the error in the text below. Do you have any idea?

> 'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U6eR.png)

Answer (score 20):

In vite.config.js add:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
    },
}
```

in define field

Comment: Had the same issue with vue as well. Using the above configurations fixed the issue.

Answer (score 15):

Working config for React polyfilled for AWS SDK and Amplify

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: "globalThis", //<-- AWS SDK 
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        // Enable rollup polyfills plugin
        // used during production bundling
        rollupNodePolyFill(),
      ],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser', // <-- Fix from above
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

when using an array of aliases.

```js
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
      {
        find: './runtimeConfig', replacement: './runtimeConfig.browser',
      }

    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the issue "'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external", just install the http package (e.g 'npm i http')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It appears root cause of this type of issue is that `aws-amplify` JS lib is relying on Node specific features. There is a two part workaround:

1. To solve errors like `'xxxxx' is not exported by __vite-browser-external` add additional alias for `./runtimeConfig` to the `vite.config.ts` file. So it will look something like:

```
alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
    },
```

2. To solve error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`, declare corresponding global variable in your topmost html file (`index.html`)

```
<script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
</script>
```

There is github issue open for more than a year now: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9639